# How do I make WRAP_CONTENT work on a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a `DialogFragment` that contains a `RecyclerView` (a list of cards).

Within this `RecyclerView` are one or more `CardViews` that can have any height.

I want to give this `DialogFragment` the correct height based on the `CardViews` that are contained within.

Normally this would be simple, I would set `wrap_content` on the `RecyclerView` like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView ...
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:clickable="true"   
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Because I am using a `RecyclerView` this does not work:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37001674

and

[Nested Recycler view height doesn't wrap its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content)

On both of these pages people suggest to extend `LinearLayoutManager` and to override `onMeasure()`

I first used the **LayoutManager** that someone provided in the first link:

```
public static class WrappingLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

        public WrappingLayoutManager(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

        @Override
        public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                              int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
            final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
            final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
            final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
            final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

            measureScrapChild(recycler, 0,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            int width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            int height = mMeasuredDimension[1];

            switch (widthMode) {
                case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                    width = widthSize;
                    break;
                case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            }

            switch (heightMode) {
                case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                    height = heightSize;
                    break;
                case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            }

            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }

        private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                       int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
            View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
            if (view != null) {
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                        getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
                int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                        getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
                view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
                measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth();
                measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight();
                recycler.recycleView(view);
            }
        }
    }
```

However **this did not work** because

`heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);`

returns a very large value that appear to be related to `match_parent`.

By commenting  `height = heightSize;` (in the second switch case) I managed to make the height work but only if a `TextView` child inside the `CardView` does not wrap its own text (a long sentence).

As soon as that `TextView` wraps it's own text the height SHOULD increase but it doesn't. It calculated the height for that long sentence as a single line, not a wrapped line (2 or more).

Any advice on how I should improve this `LayoutManager` so my `RecyclerView` works with `WRAP_CONTENT`?

**Edit: This layout manager might work for most people, but it still has problems with scrolling and calculating heights of wrapping textviews**

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                      int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension);

        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }
    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            width = widthSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            height = heightSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that Google [finally managed to fix that](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772#c42): `Jan 22, 2016: This has been merged into the internal tree, should be available with the next version of support library.`

Answer (score 192, accepted):

From [Android Support Library 23.2.1](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions) update, all **WRAP_CONTENT** should work correctly.

Please update version of a library in `gradle` file **OR** to further :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

solved some issue like *Fixed bugs related to various measure-spec methods*

Check http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview

you can check [Support Library revision history](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

Comment: I was using a LayoutManager and immediately I updated to `23.2.0` it starts crashing my app. So, I followed your answer and my `RecyclerView` isn't wrapping. Why?

Comment: Fixed. I wrote my custom LayoutManager to wrap_content of the items in Recycler View but after updating it started crashing with an index based exception. And when I removed it, it didn't crash again but my view was not wrapping until I initialized the Recycler View with a LinearLayoutManager.

Comment: nice to hear that @ItuokeAjanlekoko

Comment: Don't forget to call `mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` otherwise the recycler view will still handle the scrolling itself instead to pass the events to the parents.

Comment: This has the whole explanation http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: I still can't get it to work for me for some reaso on version 23.3.0

Comment: @fobbymaster Make sure your library is >= 23.2.1. I thought I was using the 23.3.0 but actually it was just a sub note saying to update to 23.3.0 (Xamarin Studio Nuget Package Manager) but I was actually on 23.1.1

Comment: Wrap-Content for RecyclerView not quite supported yet. Check out https://medium.com/@elye.project/recyclerview-supported-wrap-content-not-quite-f04a942ce624#.n7xivnrdr

Comment: how and 26.0.0 version too

Comment: This is not the solution for the given problem. Even in version 27 of Support is not working. The solution is told in next answer from orange01, to wrap the RecyclerView inside a RelativeLayout.

Comment: is that a reason why this is accepted as a answer?@Christian

Comment: @AmitVaghela using support library 23 is not a solution and this doesn't work in 27

Comment: Also make sure you are not calling `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)`

Answer (score 105):

**UPDATE 02.07.2020**
This method may prevent recycling and **should not be used on large data sets**.

**UPDATE 05.07.2019**

If you are using `RecyclerView` inside a `ScrollView`, just change `ScrollView` to `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView`. Inside this view there is no need to pack `RecyclerView` inside a `RelativeLayout`.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- other views -->

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- other views -->

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

---

Finally found the solution for this problem.

All you need to do is wrap the `RecyclerView` in a `RelativeLayout`. Maybe there are other Views which may also work.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i don't know why your solution is right. But It works for me. Thank you very much <3

Comment: Same.. tried a bunch of things but somehow this worked. No idea why or how. Thank you very much! FrameLayout didn't work for me, but RelativeLayout did.

Comment: This also worked for me when I was using the RecyclerView inside a ConstraintLayout.

Comment: this didn't work for me until i set both height AND width for recyclerview to "match_parent"

Comment: This worked for me, I also have rember when I saw it I have use it in the past, Thank you @orange01!!

Comment: It works with LinearLayoutManager and not with StaggeredGridLayoutManager!!

Comment: You say that it prevents recycling. What is the proper way to do this without preventing recycling?

Comment: Thanks! Only after putted RecycleView inside RelativeLayout my code worked well.

Comment: why its not work for me , i have tried :(

Comment: my device is android 9

Comment: Also note that you MUST NOT set recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true) on wrap_content RecyclerView

Answer (score 53):

Here is the refined version of the class which seems to work and lacks problems other solutions have:

```
package org.solovyev.android.views.llm;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * {@link android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager} which wraps its content. Note that this class will always
 * wrap the content regardless of {@link android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView} layout parameters.
 *
 * Now it's impossible to run add/remove animations with child views which have arbitrary dimensions (height for
 * VERTICAL orientation and width for HORIZONTAL). However if child views have fixed dimensions
 * {@link #setChildSize(int)} method might be used to let the layout manager know how big they are going to be.
 * If animations are not used at all then a normal measuring procedure will run and child views will be measured during
 * the measure pass.
 */
public class LinearLayoutManager extends android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager {

    private static final int CHILD_WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int CHILD_HEIGHT = 1;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE = 100;

    private final int[] childDimensions = new int[2];

    private int childSize = DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE;
    private boolean hasChildSize;

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public LinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public LinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public static int makeUnspecifiedSpec() {
        return View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);

        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

        final boolean exactWidth = widthMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
        final boolean exactHeight = heightMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

        final int unspecified = makeUnspecifiedSpec();

        if (exactWidth && exactHeight) {
            // in case of exact calculations for both dimensions let's use default "onMeasure" implementation
            super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
            return;
        }

        final boolean vertical = getOrientation() == VERTICAL;

        initChildDimensions(widthSize, heightSize, vertical);

        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;

        // it's possible to get scrap views in recycler which are bound to old (invalid) adapter entities. This
        // happens because their invalidation happens after "onMeasure" method. As a workaround let's clear the
        // recycler now (it should not cause any performance issues while scrolling as "onMeasure" is never
        // called whiles scrolling)
        recycler.clear();

        final int stateItemCount = state.getItemCount();
        final int adapterItemCount = getItemCount();
        // adapter always contains actual data while state might contain old data (f.e. data before the animation is
        // done). As we want to measure the view with actual data we must use data from the adapter and not from  the
        // state
        for (int i = 0; i < adapterItemCount; i++) {
            if (vertical) {
                if (!hasChildSize) {
                    if (i < stateItemCount) {
                        // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items
                        // we will use previously calculated dimensions
                        measureChild(recycler, i, widthSpec, unspecified, childDimensions);
                    } else {
                        logMeasureWarning(i);
                    }
                }
                height += childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
                }
                if (height >= heightSize) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (!hasChildSize) {
                    if (i < stateItemCount) {
                        // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items
                        // we will use previously calculated dimensions
                        measureChild(recycler, i, unspecified, heightSpec, childDimensions);
                    } else {
                        logMeasureWarning(i);
                    }
                }
                width += childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
                }
                if (width >= widthSize) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ((vertical && height < heightSize) || (!vertical && width < widthSize)) {
            // we really should wrap the contents of the view, let's do it

            if (exactWidth) {
                width = widthSize;
            } else {
                width += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
            }

            if (exactHeight) {
                height = heightSize;
            } else {
                height += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
            }

            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            // if calculated height/width exceeds requested height/width let's use default "onMeasure" implementation
            super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
        }
    }

    private void logMeasureWarning(int child) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.w("LinearLayoutManager", "Can't measure child #" + child + ", previously used dimensions will be reused." +
                    "To remove this message either use #setChildSize() method or don't run RecyclerView animations");
        }
    }

    private void initChildDimensions(int width, int height, boolean vertical) {
        if (childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] != 0 || childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] != 0) {
            // already initialized, skipping
            return;
        }
        if (vertical) {
            childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = width;
            childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = childSize;
        } else {
            childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = childSize;
            childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = height;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
        // might be called before the constructor of this class is called
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (childDimensions != null) {
            if (getOrientation() != orientation) {
                childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = 0;
                childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = 0;
            }
        }
        super.setOrientation(orientation);
    }

    public void clearChildSize() {
        hasChildSize = false;
        setChildSize(DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE);
    }

    public void setChildSize(int childSize) {
        hasChildSize = true;
        if (this.childSize != childSize) {
            this.childSize = childSize;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    private void measureChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec, int heightSpec, int[] dimensions) {
        final View child = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);

        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        final int hPadding = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        final int vPadding = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

        final int hMargin = p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        final int vMargin = p.topMargin + p.bottomMargin;

        final int hDecoration = getRightDecorationWidth(child) + getLeftDecorationWidth(child);
        final int vDecoration = getTopDecorationHeight(child) + getBottomDecorationHeight(child);

        final int childWidthSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec, hPadding + hMargin + hDecoration, p.width, canScrollHorizontally());
        final int childHeightSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec, vPadding + vMargin + vDecoration, p.height, canScrollVertically());

        child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

        dimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(child) + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        dimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(child) + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;

        recycler.recycleView(child);
    }
}
```

This is also available as a [library](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager). Link to [relevant class](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/solovyev/android/views/llm/LinearLayoutManager.java).

Comment: Works flawlessly for me. Thank you.

Comment: Please, use an up-to-date version from [github](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager) as it has changed a lot since I posted the answer.

Comment: thank you for your work. I'm having troubles working with different-height childs. If I have 10 150dp childs, it works; if one of them is 300dp, the last one will be hidden. Any idea?

Comment: More specifically, I feel like it measures childs before `onBindViewHolder()` is called. That is bad because at that point I call, for example, `holder.textView.setText(longText)`, so that child becomes taller, but it is not reflected into the recycler height. If you have any idea (like quick changes to the adapter), I'd be grateful.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer/library helped me in overcoming the problem of height of the [horizontal `RecyclerView` inside vertical `RecyclerView`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32115534/1276636).

Comment: @mvai have you resolved this problem of changing height after `onBindViewHolder()` ?

Comment: @John nope, doesn't work for me. Let me know if you find something :-)

Comment: Worked fine for me until i've started to use Android Data Binding. Same problem as @mvai has.

Comment: @user527759 Since I was showing only 10 items at I time (with "next page" and "previous page" buttons), I switched to a custom LinearLayout. I populate it at runtime using addView(), and I reuse child views when changing the adapter data. Not suggested, though, if you want to show a big number of items.

Comment: @mvai for a now i've overcome the issue by adding dirty hack to binding pattern like setting value manually in the onBindViewHolder method for the TextView which may take few lines and has "wrap_content" height. `viewHolder.binding.setMyData`...`viewHolder.binding.myTextView.setText(longText)`

Comment: Generally it works well, but when I add an `ItemDecoration` to my `RecyclerView` which makes some offsets to its child views, the measured height will be slightly smaller than `wrap_content`.

Comment: No need to use a custom LayoutManager. All you need is to draw the RecyclerView last. Check my answer.

Comment: After using this, I am having issues with my data binding. Keeps copying values to the rest of the items which were supposed to be empty.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in horizontal layout. Used second layout manager from original question, works not perfect, but at least shows content.

Comment: If the RecyclerView is nested in a SwipeRefreshLayout, it doesn't work (it works well otherwise, but not in this case).

Comment: Explanation to my previous comment. If you try to add default values to layouts and then try to populate your items with different values, those different values will override the default values where default values were required which is a problem since we are trying to reduce if else conditions. In order to use this LinearLayout youll have to have if/else condition that replaces null to your default values in code.

Comment: This is only working for me for a Horizontal ``LayoutManager`` if I set my ``RecyclerView`` layout_width to "wrap_content" and nest it in a ``RelativeLayout`` with ``layout_center_horizontal=true`` set in my ``RecyclerView``. Otherwise, it doesn´t work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATE**

By Android Support Library 23.2 update, all WRAP_CONTENT should work correctly.

Please update version of a library in gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

*Original Answer*

As answered on other question, you need to use original onMeasure() method when your recycler view height is bigger than screen height. This layout manager can calculate ItemDecoration and can scroll with more.

```
    public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                      int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension);

        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }

    // If child view is more than screen size, there is no need to make it wrap content. We can use original onMeasure() so we can scroll view.
    if (height < heightSize && width < widthSize) {

        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                width = widthSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                height = heightSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
    }
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                               int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {

   View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);

   // For adding Item Decor Insets to view
   super.measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0);
    if (view != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getDecoratedLeft(view) + getDecoratedRight(view), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + getPaddingBottom() + getDecoratedBottom(view) , p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

            // Get decorated measurements
            measuredDimension[0] = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view) + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view) + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

original answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28510031/1577792

Comment: How can we achieve the same for `gridlayoutmanager` and `staggeredgridlayoutmanager` considering span count in mind

Answer (score 9):

Here is the ***c# version for mono android***

```
/* 
* Ported by Jagadeesh Govindaraj (@jaganjan)
 *Copyright 2015 serso aka se.solovyev
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Contact details
 *
 * Email: se.solovyev @gmail.com
 * Site:  http://se.solovyev.org
 */


using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Lang.Reflect;
using System;
using Math = Java.Lang.Math;

namespace Droid.Helper
{
    public class WrapLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager
    {
        private const int DefaultChildSize = 100;
        private static readonly Rect TmpRect = new Rect();
        private int _childSize = DefaultChildSize;
        private static bool _canMakeInsetsDirty = true;
        private static readonly int[] ChildDimensions = new int[2];
        private const int ChildHeight = 1;
        private const int ChildWidth = 0;
        private static bool _hasChildSize;
        private static  Field InsetsDirtyField = null;
        private static int _overScrollMode = ViewCompat.OverScrollAlways;
        private static RecyclerView _view;

        public WrapLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, bool reverseLayout)
            : base(context, orientation, reverseLayout)
        {
            _view = null;
        }

        public WrapLayoutManager(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _view = null;
        }

        public WrapLayoutManager(RecyclerView view) : base(view.Context)
        {
            _view = view;
            _overScrollMode = ViewCompat.GetOverScrollMode(view);
        }

        public WrapLayoutManager(RecyclerView view, int orientation, bool reverseLayout)
            : base(view.Context, orientation, reverseLayout)
        {
            _view = view;
            _overScrollMode = ViewCompat.GetOverScrollMode(view);
        }

        public void SetOverScrollMode(int overScrollMode)
        {
            if (overScrollMode < ViewCompat.OverScrollAlways || overScrollMode > ViewCompat.OverScrollNever)
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown overscroll mode: " + overScrollMode);
            if (_view == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_view));
            _overScrollMode = overScrollMode;
            ViewCompat.SetOverScrollMode(_view, overScrollMode);
        }

        public static int MakeUnspecifiedSpec()
        {
            return View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);
        }

        public override void OnMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec,
            int heightSpec)
        {
            var widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.GetMode(widthSpec);
            var heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.GetMode(heightSpec);

            var widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthSpec);
            var heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.GetSize(heightSpec);

            var hasWidthSize = widthMode != MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified;
            var hasHeightSize = heightMode != MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified;

            var exactWidth = widthMode == MeasureSpecMode.Exactly;
            var exactHeight = heightMode == MeasureSpecMode.Exactly;

            var unspecified = MakeUnspecifiedSpec();

            if (exactWidth && exactHeight)
            {
                // in case of exact calculations for both dimensions let's use default "onMeasure" implementation
                base.OnMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
                return;
            }

            var vertical = Orientation == Vertical;

            InitChildDimensions(widthSize, heightSize, vertical);

            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;

            // it's possible to get scrap views in recycler which are bound to old (invalid) adapter
            // entities. This happens because their invalidation happens after "onMeasure" method.
            // As a workaround let's clear the recycler now (it should not cause any performance
            // issues while scrolling as "onMeasure" is never called whiles scrolling)
            recycler.Clear();

            var stateItemCount = state.ItemCount;
            var adapterItemCount = ItemCount;
            // adapter always contains actual data while state might contain old data (f.e. data
            // before the animation is done). As we want to measure the view with actual data we
            // must use data from the adapter and not from the state
            for (var i = 0; i < adapterItemCount; i++)
            {
                if (vertical)
                {
                    if (!_hasChildSize)
                    {
                        if (i < stateItemCount)
                        {
                            // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get
                            // IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items we will use previously
                            // calculated dimensions
                            MeasureChild(recycler, i, widthSize, unspecified, ChildDimensions);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LogMeasureWarning(i);
                        }
                    }
                    height += ChildDimensions[ChildHeight];
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        width = ChildDimensions[ChildWidth];
                    }
                    if (hasHeightSize && height >= heightSize)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!_hasChildSize)
                    {
                        if (i < stateItemCount)
                        {
                            // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get
                            // IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items we will use previously
                            // calculated dimensions
                            MeasureChild(recycler, i, unspecified, heightSize, ChildDimensions);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LogMeasureWarning(i);
                        }
                    }
                    width += ChildDimensions[ChildWidth];
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        height = ChildDimensions[ChildHeight];
                    }
                    if (hasWidthSize && width >= widthSize)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (exactWidth)
            {
                width = widthSize;
            }
            else
            {
                width += PaddingLeft + PaddingRight;
                if (hasWidthSize)
                {
                    width = Math.Min(width, widthSize);
                }
            }

            if (exactHeight)
            {
                height = heightSize;
            }
            else
            {
                height += PaddingTop + PaddingBottom;
                if (hasHeightSize)
                {
                    height = Math.Min(height, heightSize);
                }
            }

            SetMeasuredDimension(width, height);

            if (_view == null || _overScrollMode != ViewCompat.OverScrollIfContentScrolls) return;
            var fit = (vertical && (!hasHeightSize || height < heightSize))
                      || (!vertical && (!hasWidthSize || width < widthSize));

            ViewCompat.SetOverScrollMode(_view, fit ? ViewCompat.OverScrollNever : ViewCompat.OverScrollAlways);
        }

        private void LogMeasureWarning(int child)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Warn, "LinearLayoutManager",
                "Can't measure child #" + child + ", previously used dimensions will be reused." +
                "To remove this message either use #SetChildSize() method or don't run RecyclerView animations");
#endif
        }

        private void InitChildDimensions(int width, int height, bool vertical)
        {
            if (ChildDimensions[ChildWidth] != 0 || ChildDimensions[ChildHeight] != 0)
            {
                // already initialized, skipping
                return;
            }
            if (vertical)
            {
                ChildDimensions[ChildWidth] = width;
                ChildDimensions[ChildHeight] = _childSize;
            }
            else
            {
                ChildDimensions[ChildWidth] = _childSize;
                ChildDimensions[ChildHeight] = height;
            }
        }

        public void ClearChildSize()
        {
            _hasChildSize = false;
            SetChildSize(DefaultChildSize);
        }

        public void SetChildSize(int size)
        {
            _hasChildSize = true;
            if (_childSize == size) return;
            _childSize = size;
            RequestLayout();
        }

        private void MeasureChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSize, int heightSize,
            int[] dimensions)
        {
            View child = null;
            try
            {
                child = recycler.GetViewForPosition(position);
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
            {
                Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Warn, "LinearLayoutManager",
                    "LinearLayoutManager doesn't work well with animations. Consider switching them off", e);
            }

            if (child != null)
            {
                var p = child.LayoutParameters.JavaCast<RecyclerView.LayoutParams>()

                var hPadding = PaddingLeft + PaddingRight;
                var vPadding = PaddingTop + PaddingBottom;

                var hMargin = p.LeftMargin + p.RightMargin;
                var vMargin = p.TopMargin + p.BottomMargin;

                // we must make insets dirty in order calculateItemDecorationsForChild to work
                MakeInsetsDirty(p);
                // this method should be called before any getXxxDecorationXxx() methods
                CalculateItemDecorationsForChild(child, TmpRect);

                var hDecoration = GetRightDecorationWidth(child) + GetLeftDecorationWidth(child);
                var vDecoration = GetTopDecorationHeight(child) + GetBottomDecorationHeight(child);

                var childWidthSpec = GetChildMeasureSpec(widthSize, hPadding + hMargin + hDecoration, p.Width,
                    CanScrollHorizontally());
                var childHeightSpec = GetChildMeasureSpec(heightSize, vPadding + vMargin + vDecoration, p.Height,
                    CanScrollVertically());

                child.Measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

                dimensions[ChildWidth] = GetDecoratedMeasuredWidth(child) + p.LeftMargin + p.RightMargin;
                dimensions[ChildHeight] = GetDecoratedMeasuredHeight(child) + p.BottomMargin + p.TopMargin;

                // as view is recycled let's not keep old measured values
                MakeInsetsDirty(p);
            }
            recycler.RecycleView(child);
        }

        private static void MakeInsetsDirty(RecyclerView.LayoutParams p)
        {
            if (!_canMakeInsetsDirty)
            {
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                if (InsetsDirtyField == null)
                {
                   var klass = Java.Lang.Class.FromType (typeof (RecyclerView.LayoutParams));
                    InsetsDirtyField = klass.GetDeclaredField("mInsetsDirty");
                    InsetsDirtyField.Accessible = true;
                }
                InsetsDirtyField.Set(p, true);
            }
            catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
            {
                OnMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                OnMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
            }
        }

        private static void OnMakeInsertDirtyFailed()
        {
            _canMakeInsetsDirty = false;
#if DEBUG
            Log.Warn("LinearLayoutManager",
                "Can't make LayoutParams insets dirty, decorations measurements might be incorrect");
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: almost... replace
```var p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.LayoutParameters```
with
```var p = child.LayoutParameters.JavaCast<RecyclerView.LayoutParams>()```

Comment: why do you declare the member variables static?

Comment: @esskar i think the variable are used in static methods,look at java version if u have any doubts

Answer (score 7):

> Put the recyclerview in any other layout (Relative layout is
> preferable). Then change recyclerview's height/width as match parent
> to that layout and set the parent layout's height/width as wrap
> content.

Source: [This comment.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view/issues/53#issuecomment-362991531)

Comment: I also added `match_parent` for my item.

Answer (score 6):

`RecyclerView` added support for `wrap_content` in `23.2.0` which was buggy , 23.2.1 was just stable , so you can use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
```

You can see the revision history here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

**Note:**

Also note that after updating support library the `RecyclerView` will respect `wrap_content` as well as `match_parent` so if you have a Item View of a `RecyclerView` set as `match_parent` the single view will fill whole screen

Comment: @Yvette ok sure

Answer (score 6):

Simply put your RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView. Works perfectly

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/kliste"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with scrolling and text wrapping is that this code is assuming that both the width and the height are set to `wrap_content`. However, the `LayoutManager` needs to know that the horizontal width is constrained. So instead of creating your own `widthSpec` for each child view, just use the original `widthSpec`:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                widthSpec,
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension);

        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }
    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            width = widthSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            height = heightSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
    View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
    if (view != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
        view.measure(widthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
        recycler.recycleView(view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (It's a nasty solution but It may work):
In the `onCreate` method of your `Activity` or in the `onViewCreated` method of your fragment. Set a callback ready to be triggered when the `RecyclerView` first render, like this:

```
vRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                calculeRecyclerViewFullHeight();
            }
        });
```

In the `calculeRecyclerViewFullHeight` calculate the `RecyclerView` full height based in the height of its children.

```
protected void calculateSwipeRefreshFullHeight() {
        int height = 0;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < getRecyclerView().getChildCount(); idx++ ) {
            View v = getRecyclerView().getChildAt(idx);
            height += v.getHeight();
        }
        SwipeRefreshLayout.LayoutParams params = getSwipeRefresh().getLayoutParams();
        params.height = height;
        getSwipeRefresh().setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

In my case my `RecyclerView` is contain in a `SwipeRefreshLayout` for that reason I'm setting the height to the `SwipeRefreshView` and not to the `RecyclerView` but if you don't have any `SwipeRefreshView` then you can set the height to the `RecyclerView` instead.

Let me know if this helped you or not.

Comment: How do I get the getRecyclerView() method?

Comment: @asubanovsky It's a method that just returns your `RecyclerView` instance.

Comment: Remember to remove your globalLayoutListener in onGlobalLayout()

Answer (score 3):

This now works as they've made a release in version 23.2, as stated in this [post](https://code.google.com/u/117115245040694940719/).
Quoting the official [blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

> This release brings an exciting new feature to the LayoutManager API: auto-measurement! This allows a RecyclerView to size itself based on the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable scenarios, such as using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the RecyclerView, are now possible. You’ll find all built in LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement.

Answer (score 3):

i suggest you to put  the recyclerview in any other layout (Relative layout is preferable). Then change recyclerview's  height/width as match parent to that layout and set the parent layout's height/width as wrap content. it works for me

Answer (score 2):

I had used some of the above solutions but it was working for `width` but `height`.

1. If your specified `compileSdkVersion` greater than **23**, you can directly use **RecyclerView** provided in their respective support libraries of recycler view, like for **23** it will be `'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'`. These **support libraries** support attributes of `wrap_content` for both width and height.

You have to add it to your dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

2. If your `compileSdkVersion` less than **23**, you can use below-mentioned solution.

I found this [Google thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772) regarding this issue. In this thread, there is one contribution which leads to the implementation of [LinearLayoutManager](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/solovyev/android/views/llm/LinearLayoutManager.java).

**I have tested it for both *height* and *width* and it worked fine for me in both cases.**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2015 serso aka se.solovyev
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Contact details
 *
 * Email: se.solovyev@gmail.com
 * Site:  http://se.solovyev.org
 */

package org.solovyev.android.views.llm;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/**
 * {@link android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager} which wraps its content. Note that this class will always
 * wrap the content regardless of {@link android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView} layout parameters.
 * <p/>
 * Now it's impossible to run add/remove animations with child views which have arbitrary dimensions (height for
 * VERTICAL orientation and width for HORIZONTAL). However if child views have fixed dimensions
 * {@link #setChildSize(int)} method might be used to let the layout manager know how big they are going to be.
 * If animations are not used at all then a normal measuring procedure will run and child views will be measured during
 * the measure pass.
 */
public class LinearLayoutManager extends android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager {

    private static boolean canMakeInsetsDirty = true;
    private static Field insetsDirtyField = null;

    private static final int CHILD_WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int CHILD_HEIGHT = 1;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE = 100;

    private final int[] childDimensions = new int[2];
    private final RecyclerView view;

    private int childSize = DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE;
    private boolean hasChildSize;
    private int overScrollMode = ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS;
    private final Rect tmpRect = new Rect();

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public LinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.view = null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public LinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
        this.view = null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public LinearLayoutManager(RecyclerView view) {
        super(view.getContext());
        this.view = view;
        this.overScrollMode = ViewCompat.getOverScrollMode(view);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public LinearLayoutManager(RecyclerView view, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(view.getContext(), orientation, reverseLayout);
        this.view = view;
        this.overScrollMode = ViewCompat.getOverScrollMode(view);
    }

    public void setOverScrollMode(int overScrollMode) {
        if (overScrollMode < ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS || overScrollMode > ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown overscroll mode: " + overScrollMode);
        if (this.view == null) throw new IllegalStateException("view == null");
        this.overScrollMode = overScrollMode;
        ViewCompat.setOverScrollMode(view, overScrollMode);
    }

    public static int makeUnspecifiedSpec() {
        return View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);

        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

        final boolean hasWidthSize = widthMode != View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;
        final boolean hasHeightSize = heightMode != View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;

        final boolean exactWidth = widthMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
        final boolean exactHeight = heightMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

        final int unspecified = makeUnspecifiedSpec();

        if (exactWidth && exactHeight) {
            // in case of exact calculations for both dimensions let's use default "onMeasure" implementation
            super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
            return;
        }

        final boolean vertical = getOrientation() == VERTICAL;

        initChildDimensions(widthSize, heightSize, vertical);

        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;

        // it's possible to get scrap views in recycler which are bound to old (invalid) adapter entities. This
        // happens because their invalidation happens after "onMeasure" method. As a workaround let's clear the
        // recycler now (it should not cause any performance issues while scrolling as "onMeasure" is never
        // called whiles scrolling)
        recycler.clear();

        final int stateItemCount = state.getItemCount();
        final int adapterItemCount = getItemCount();
        // adapter always contains actual data while state might contain old data (f.e. data before the animation is
        // done). As we want to measure the view with actual data we must use data from the adapter and not from  the
        // state
        for (int i = 0; i < adapterItemCount; i++) {
            if (vertical) {
                if (!hasChildSize) {
                    if (i < stateItemCount) {
                        // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items
                        // we will use previously calculated dimensions
                        measureChild(recycler, i, widthSize, unspecified, childDimensions);
                    } else {
                        logMeasureWarning(i);
                    }
                }
                height += childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
                }
                if (hasHeightSize && height >= heightSize) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (!hasChildSize) {
                    if (i < stateItemCount) {
                        // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items
                        // we will use previously calculated dimensions
                        measureChild(recycler, i, unspecified, heightSize, childDimensions);
                    } else {
                        logMeasureWarning(i);
                    }
                }
                width += childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
                }
                if (hasWidthSize && width >= widthSize) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (exactWidth) {
            width = widthSize;
        } else {
            width += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
            if (hasWidthSize) {
                width = Math.min(width, widthSize);
            }
        }

        if (exactHeight) {
            height = heightSize;
        } else {
            height += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
            if (hasHeightSize) {
                height = Math.min(height, heightSize);
            }
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (view != null && overScrollMode == ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS) {
            final boolean fit = (vertical && (!hasHeightSize || height < heightSize))
                    || (!vertical && (!hasWidthSize || width < widthSize));

            ViewCompat.setOverScrollMode(view, fit ? ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER : ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
        }
    }

    private void logMeasureWarning(int child) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.w("LinearLayoutManager", "Can't measure child #" + child + ", previously used dimensions will be reused." +
                    "To remove this message either use #setChildSize() method or don't run RecyclerView animations");
        }
    }

    private void initChildDimensions(int width, int height, boolean vertical) {
        if (childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] != 0 || childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] != 0) {
            // already initialized, skipping
            return;
        }
        if (vertical) {
            childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = width;
            childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = childSize;
        } else {
            childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = childSize;
            childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = height;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
        // might be called before the constructor of this class is called
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (childDimensions != null) {
            if (getOrientation() != orientation) {
                childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = 0;
                childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = 0;
            }
        }
        super.setOrientation(orientation);
    }

    public void clearChildSize() {
        hasChildSize = false;
        setChildSize(DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE);
    }

    public void setChildSize(int childSize) {
        hasChildSize = true;
        if (this.childSize != childSize) {
            this.childSize = childSize;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    private void measureChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSize, int heightSize, int[] dimensions) {
        final View child;
        try {
            child = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.w("LinearLayoutManager", "LinearLayoutManager doesn't work well with animations. Consider switching them off", e);
            }
            return;
        }

        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        final int hPadding = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        final int vPadding = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

        final int hMargin = p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        final int vMargin = p.topMargin + p.bottomMargin;

        // we must make insets dirty in order calculateItemDecorationsForChild to work
        makeInsetsDirty(p);
        // this method should be called before any getXxxDecorationXxx() methods
        calculateItemDecorationsForChild(child, tmpRect);

        final int hDecoration = getRightDecorationWidth(child) + getLeftDecorationWidth(child);
        final int vDecoration = getTopDecorationHeight(child) + getBottomDecorationHeight(child);

        final int childWidthSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(widthSize, hPadding + hMargin + hDecoration, p.width, canScrollHorizontally());
        final int childHeightSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(heightSize, vPadding + vMargin + vDecoration, p.height, canScrollVertically());

        child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

        dimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(child) + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        dimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(child) + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;

        // as view is recycled let's not keep old measured values
        makeInsetsDirty(p);
        recycler.recycleView(child);
    }

    private static void makeInsetsDirty(RecyclerView.LayoutParams p) {
        if (!canMakeInsetsDirty) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (insetsDirtyField == null) {
                insetsDirtyField = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.class.getDeclaredField("mInsetsDirty");
                insetsDirtyField.setAccessible(true);
            }
            insetsDirtyField.set(p, true);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            onMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            onMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
        }
    }

    private static void onMakeInsertDirtyFailed() {
        canMakeInsetsDirty = false;
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.w("LinearLayoutManager", "Can't make LayoutParams insets dirty, decorations measurements might be incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using any library, easiest solution till the new version comes out is to just open [b.android.com/74772](http://b.android.com/74772#c50). You'll easily find the best solution known to date there.

PS: [b.android.com/74772#c50](http://b.android.com/74772#c50) worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Update your view with null value instead of parent viewgroup in Adapter viewholder onCreateViewHolder method.

```
@Override
public AdapterItemSku.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, null, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also check if auto measure is enabled on the layout manager. if not:  `layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `measureScrapChild` to follow code:

```
private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
        int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension)
    {
        View view = recycler.GetViewForPosition(position);
        if (view != null)
        {
            MeasureChildWithMargins(view, widthSpec, heightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.MeasuredWidth;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.MeasuredHeight;
            recycler.RecycleView(view);
        }
    }
```

I use xamarin, so this is c# code. I think this can be easily "translated" to Java.

Answer (score 0):

You must put a FrameLayout as Main view then put inside a RelativeLayout with ScrollView and at least your RecyclerView, it works for me.

The real trick here is the RelativeLayout...

Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem similar to you and I can solve it by using `LayoutManager` as `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` instead of trying to apply with `LinearLayoutManager` by calculate screen width or `GridLayoutManager`

Please find sample code bellow without required you to do any other customization

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager horizontalManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(spanCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalManager);
```

Note: `spanCount` is number of item per row but it will auto wrap-content for you if current RecyclerView item reach the screen width.

Hope it can help you and good luck!!!

Answer (score -2):

I have not worked on my answer but the way I know it StaggridLayoutManager with no. of grid 1 can solve your problem as StaggridLayout will automatically adjust its height and width on the size of the content.