# Two RecyclerViews under each other in one layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I get two RecyclerViews under each other in one layout? I don't want to have a single RecyclerView for all items.
My code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/main__item_background"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/find_friends__already_playing"
    android:background="@color/header"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_header"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/in_app_friends"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:text="@string/find_friends__invite_friends"
    android:background="@color/find_friends__header"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_header" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/friends_to_invite"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've found the answer myself.

You need to put the LinearLayout into a **ScrollView** and use `wrap_content` as RecyclerView's `layout_height`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_header"
        android:background="@color/header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/find_friends__already_playing"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/in_app_friends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_header"
        android:background="@color/find_friends__header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/find_friends__invite_friends" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/friends_to_invite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Also there is a bug with with RecyclerView and `wrap_content` so you have to use a **custom layout manager**. Check out this post: [How do I make WRAP_CONTENT work on a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview)

Comment: You should just be using one `RecyclerView` with different item view types. `RecyclerView.Adapter` has a `getItemViewType(int position)` that will be passed into `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int itemtype)` where you can switch on the type and create the correct `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

Comment: What should I do, when I have to use different models in the recyclerviews?

Comment: `wrap_content` is now **fixed** in the latest  Android Support Library **no need** to write a custom layout manager

Comment: for smooth scrolling it's better to set also recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) on each one of the recycler views

Comment: The last point is outdated: [starting from **AppCompat v23.2**, all built-in LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html#recyclerview). `Previously unavailable scenarios, such as using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the RecyclerView, are now possible.`

Comment: best solution is use nested scrollview

Comment: android's documentation explicitly [advises against](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) adding `RecyclerView` or `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 36):

You should create an XML layout file like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/ingredients_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/steps_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And in the code, you should call `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`

```
RecyclerView ingredientsList = findViewById(R.id.ingredients_list);
RecyclerView stepsList = findViewById(R.id.steps_list);

ingredientsList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
stepsList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: appreciated i was stacked whole day

Comment: ingredientsList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
stepsList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false).  working

Answer (score 9):

I also had the same problem and wrote a library which helps to achieve this by joining adapters and layouts.

Gradle dependency to try it (needs jcenter repo):

```
compile 'su.j2e:rv-joiner:1.0.3'//latest version by now
```

Thea change xml to use a single RecyclerView which matches parent:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/joined_friends_rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"/>
```

Then init RecyclerView in code like this:

```
    //init your RecyclerView as usual
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.joined_friends_rv);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //construct a joiner
    RvJoiner rvJoiner = new RvJoiner();
    rvJoiner.add(new JoinableLayout(R.layout.your_title_for_in_app));
    rvJoiner.add(new JoinableAdapter(new YourInAppRvAdapter()));
    rvJoiner.add(new JoinableLayout(R.layout.your_title_for_invite));
    rvJoiner.add(new JoinableAdapter(new YourInviteRvAdapter()));

    //set join adapter to your RecyclerView
    rv.setAdapter(rvJoiner.getAdapter());
```

You can check [this link](https://github.com/j2esu/rv-joiner) for more library details and explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Adding this library via build.gradle creates error while syncing

Comment: hey @ReazMurshed can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left?noredirect=1#comment87836903_49952965

Answer (score 5):

if you get the bottom recyclerview not scrolling with the main content, change the LinearLayout (see answer from alan_derua) to ConstraintLayout and wrap the two RecyclerViews inside. See code below:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/task_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/first_list_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/my_tasks"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/second_list_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_list_view" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/second_list_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can give each `RecycleView` height equal to 0dp and weight equal 1:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: I don't want to them both tacking the half of the screen. I want them to be scrolled one after each other.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NestedScrollView` as parent layout, it should have

```
android:weightSum="2"
```

and give

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to each RecyclerView of yours.It should be scrolled one after each other.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/your_first_recycler"/>
```

last line is for your problem.use it.