# Recycler View below each other not showing up?

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I have two simple recycler views that I want to show directly below each other. Here is my layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/drawer_view_header"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_header"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@id/navigation_header"
            android:id="@+id/friends_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@id/friends_list"
            android:id="@+id/followers_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have my `navigationHeader` above my first recycler view called `friends_list` which works fine, and I can see the `friends_list` recycler view which has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` but the `followers_list` recycler view doesn't seem to show even though all the contents of my `friends_list` is all shown. Any ideas why it is not showing up? Thanks!

Comment: Using wrap_content won't work. You'll have to change the RelativeLayout to a vertical LinearLayout and set the RecyclerViews height using a layout_weight of 1 and layout_height of 0dp for both.

Comment: it can be happen if you set height to match parent in on`onCreateViewHolder` infalted layout of friend list recycleview

Comment: @Neil I understand what you are trying to say but I want it so that my `friends_list` recycler view appears below the `followers_list` recycler view. If I set the weight to 1 then each take up half the screen, but if `friends_list` is not filled up all the way there is a big blank space between that and the `followers_list`

Comment: @Neil oh I see what you are saying, then is there no way to show these recycler views with one underneath the other easily then aside from what you just suggested?

Comment: @user1871869 Check with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30081772/2078074). You may help from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the above answers do work they don't preserve the wrap content behavior of recycler view for that you need to use a `NestedScrollView`.

For eg you need to do something like this:-

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/drawer_view_header"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_header"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@id/navigation_header"
            android:id="@+id/friends_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@id/friends_list"
            android:id="@+id/followers_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Or you may also use a `LinearLayout` with vertical alignment in your `NestedScrollView`.

*Note:- this will only work with recycler view above 23.2.0

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set height for the recyclerview 
android provide weight to view to adjust in different screen size

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <include
        layout="@layout/drawer_view_header"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_header"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/navigation_header"
        android:id="@+id/friends_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/friends_list"
        android:id="@+id/followers_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What if I don't want to hard code the layout_height? I would prefer not to because depending on the size of the recycler view I would block certain contents

Comment: if you dont want to hard code layout_height, you can use set 'android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"` instead. this will adjust the height.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                layout="@layout/drawer_view_header"
                android:id="@+id/navigation_header"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/friends_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/followers_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since height of first `RecyclerView` is `wrap_content`, your second `RecyclerView` will not be showing up, first `RecyclerView` will occupy all the height of your layout if you have more items in it.

To solve your problem, use `LinearLayout` as root and provide equal `layout_weight` and `layout_height="0dp"` to both of your `RecyclerView`s.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/drawer_view_header"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_header"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/navigation_header"
        android:id="@+id/friends_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"    
        android:layout_weight="1"/>    <---

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/friends_list"
        android:id="@+id/followers_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"   
        android:layout_weight="1"/>    <---

</LinearLayout>
```

This will show two RercyclerViews with same space (height) occupied.

Comment: have a look at this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977521/how-to-place-adview-below-the-recyclerview-please-see-details PLEASE!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It is working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Asia"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


             android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Europe"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/cardview"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/select"
                android:text="Select all"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cardview"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/deselect"
                android:text="Deselct all"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cardview"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:text="Next activity"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```