# How to place AdView below the RecyclerView? Please see details

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml, adview

I'm developing an app in which some data is getting loaded from `Firebase` and is shown in the `RecyclerView`.

What I want is I want to show the `AdView` below the `RecyclerView` and for that I have done this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_parentLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.abc.xyz.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_ads"
        android:layout_below="@id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentPaddingBottom="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-***********/*********"
                ads:adSize="280x80">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that this layout is showing no ads at the bottom and the recyclerview is covering the whole area and the ads are getting covered by it.

Here's the screenshot (the recyclerview has been scrolled to the last and there is no ad there):

[image]

Please let me know how can I place the ads just below the `RecyclerView` or where the recyclerview ends.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`. In `LinearLayout` put ad at the bottom of the screen and let it occupy it's space and set `layout_weight` to your `RecyclerView`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ... >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ... />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And one more thing, **don't** set `layout_height` of `AdView` to `match_parent`, use `wrap_content` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your RecyclerView inside other layout, or just set layout_above="@id/card_ads"

I think the main problem is that you set in card_ads layout_below, but not tell recyclerview that it should be over the card_ads

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.abc.xyz.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="card_ads"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:contentPaddingBottom="2dp">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            ads:adSize="280x80"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-***********/*********">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've add Admob on my App, you can check at [Github](https://github.com/adleywd/WhatsNextSeries/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/content_home.xml)

**Edit:**

I put match parent, see if it works

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Strange, show us one screenshot if it's possible. Are you sure that recyclerview is covering the ads?

Comment: please see the screenshot

Comment: hey, have you taken a look at the attached screenshot?

Comment: It's a little bit hard to see with this blur... But as I can see, do you have a float button and they stay at the bottom? over the ads?

Comment: oh yeah, I want ads to remain below the `FAB` at the bottom of the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I don't think it's a good pratice, but it's up to you. Well, I've edit my answer, take a look

Comment: no :/ still not working! this has vanished the adview!

Comment: Hum... the adview was vanished means your recyclerview still over adview  even you put layout_above and below. Problably you have one xml that include this xml you show to us, right? try to put you Adview in this other xml below the include of recyclerView_parentLayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add framelayout as a main layout .Try this code .Put your adView insted of button .
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"


    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_ads"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:contentPaddingBottom="2dp">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                ads:adSize="280x80"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-***********/*********">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What's the issue with that ?Can you please share screen shot ?

Comment: please see the screenshot.

Comment: In past I've same problem due to floating button .Put floating button and recycler view in same file .And put that fab and adView in same linear of frame layout ,

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your XML

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```