# Getting gaps between recyclerview items after scrolling down and then scrolling up again. Please see details

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I have a `RecyclerView` in which I'm loading some items from the database.

The problem is that I'm getting some gaps between the items after scrolling down and up again. The gaps then remain there until I restart the app. Like this:

[image]

Here's how I have set up recyclerview in xml layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Here's how I have set it in `MainActivity.java` file:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(fastItemAdapter);
```

Here's the adapter:

```
public class HRequest extends AbstractItem<HRequest, HRequest.ViewHolder> {

        public String imageURL;

        public HRequest() {

        }

        public HRequest(String imageURL) {
            this.imageURL = imageURL;
        }

        // Fast Adapter methods
        @Override
        public int getType() {
            return R.id.recycler_view;
        }
        @Override
        public int getLayoutRes() {
            return R.layout.h_request_list_row;
        }
        @Override
        public void bindView(ViewHolder holder) {
            super.bindView(holder);

            holder.imageURL.setText(imageURL);

        }
        // Manually create the ViewHolder class
        protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView imageURL;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imageURL = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageURL);

if (!imageURL.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

if (imageURL.getText().toString().startsWith("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/") || imageURL.getText().toString().startsWith("content://")) {
                    Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                            .load(imageURL.getText().toString())
                            .into(homelessImage);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "some problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "no imageUID found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            }
        }

    }
```

What is wrong here?

Please let me know.

Comment: Can u post your adapter?

Comment: please check the updated question

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code. Post code of base adapter class and item layout, maybe it contains some bugs.

Comment: @HammadNasir post xml of  this layout R.layout.h_request_list_row ... also try to fixed height of parent layout..

Comment: thanks for the clue, Wax and Waqar. The problem was in item layout. I fixed it!

Comment: @WaqarYounis and Wax, can you have a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977521/how-to-place-adview-below-the-recyclerview-please-see-details PLEASE?..

Comment: yes.. what happend with thes question???

Comment: @WaqarYounis bhai, I have already thanked you above foe giving me clue about what is wrong. This question's problem has been fixed. Thanks

Comment: @HammadNasir i am asking about this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977521/how-to-place-adview-below-the-recyclerview-please-see-details   ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115447/discussion-between-waqar-younis-and-hammad-nasir).

Answer (score 0):

Add before add adapter:-

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));