# How can i merge two recycler views such that they scroll one after another?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081772/14599955) answer and it worked but only if the both list are prepopulated already, but in my case one list is prepopulated and the other is incremented/decremented dynamically.

Here is my layout structure
[image]

Black box represents the recycle list which can be incremented/decremented dynamically, and its main action is to show the users favorite fonts.

Red box represents all the fonts which are available and they are prepopulated.

i want both these list to flow each-other in scroll, such that user can not notice that these are actually two different list.

my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/home_section_padding"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:textColorHint=" #C0C0C0"
        android:hint="Paste"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Style"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape_for_button"
        android:onClick="fire"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyelerViewFav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyelerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />





</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can use ConcatAdapter to join few adapters

Answer (score 4):

There is 2 options, You can either use `ConcatAdapter` to combine both adapters in one adapter and use one RecyclerView (Recommended). Or use `NestedScrollView` to wrap both your RecyclerViews and  make sure to set both RecyclerView heights to wrap_content.

But based on what you are trying to achieve, I would recommend to use `ConcatAdapter(adapter1, adapter2)` to wrap both your adapters and set that new adapter on one RecyclerView. You will still be able to control each adapter by itself `Add, Remove` and calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the changed adapter will reflect changes on the RecyclerView.

Comment: how can i implement the concatAdapter thing

Comment: Here https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter

Comment: If the answer help you please mark it as the accepted answers to help others.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use two lists in one RecyclerView adapter.And have two different view holders.Whenever you need to make a change just make the change in specific array list (1 or 2) and call notifyDatasetChanged() on the single adapter you have.
Something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42450663/15377185)

Answer (score -1):

Create 2 different xml file apart from activity_main.xml ,create 2 external java file associated with these 2 XML file for user handling code purposes. Give your desired layout for recycler view in those 2 XML file,map those XML file in MainActivity.java class using some java class which will extend  RecyclerView.Adapter class and override some methods as onCreateViewHolder(),onBindViewHolder().To inflate the recycler view data ,create 1 more java file which will use some getter() & setter() inorder to populate the recycler view with data by the help of the class extending RecyclerView.Adapter class.