# How do I add a horizontal RecyclerView inside a list item

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

The task of implementation is I need to create an infinite scrollable list which will scroll both horizontally and vertically.

For this what I'm trying to do is that I have integrated a horizontal `RecyclerView` inside a vertical `ListView` item. Is this the right way to go about? I have tried other solutions but the scrolling has some issues.

The problem is that when I try to implement the `RecyclerView` inside a list item the items do not get populated.

```
public class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<ImageMedia> imageMedia;
protected Constants.IMAGE_SIZE image_size = Constants.IMAGE_SIZE.Small;
private Context context;


    public HorizontalAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        setHasStableIds(true);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_item, viewGroup, false));
    }

    protected ImageMedia getItem(int position) {
        return imageMedia.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HorizontalAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.setMedia(getItem(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (imageMedia != null ? imageMedia.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return imageMedia.get(position).getId();
    }

    //Data gets updated here
    public void setMovies(List<Movie> movie) {

            if (movie != null) {
                imageMedia = (List<ImageMedia>) (List<?>) movie;
            } else {

            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageCardView imageView;
        ImageMedia imageMedia;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = (ImageCardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            //TODO: remove this onclick

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Intent to go to the corresponding activity
                }
            });
        }

        public void setMedia(ImageMedia imageMedia) {
            this.imageMedia = imageMedia;

            imageView.loadImage(imageMedia, image_size);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use just RecyclerView, without the ListView

Comment: use this  http://nan-devblog.blogspot.in/2008/12/android-how-to-use-horizontal-scrolling.html

Comment: You can dynamically add horizontal srcollview inside Scrollview instead of using Listview with horizontal scrollview as list item.Try this links

Comment: @pskink :You mean that i use recylerView(Vertical) of RecyclerView(Horizontal) ...??

Comment: http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

Comment: @anjaneya Does nt this mean that i need to manage the item and position to handle for click events. and what if the items are more... would it not be easy if an listAdapter or an recyclerview adapter would handle the same

Comment: There is no such constructor like RecyclerView(vertical)

Comment: @pskink I mean Vertical scrolling recycler view where each item has an horizontally scrolling recyclerview

Comment: just use RecyclerView with a [Staggered]GridLayoutManager

Comment: @pskink My requirement is that... i need to scroll each item of the list horizontally, But a gridView/Staggered gridview scrolls only vertically or horizontally

Comment: Can recyclerView be added in a listView Item, ...???

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this?

Comment: I think you're facing the same problem. Try hardcoding the height of your horizontal `RecycleView` (i.e give it a height of 300dp, etc). Does this work for you too?

Comment: Thanks, Sufian. Due to some reason, the recycler view does not take up the place it should. Giving the recycler view a specific height helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

According to my understanding, the problem occurs when the system measures the list item.

The quick fix was to give horizontal `RecyclerView` a hard-coded height, but since it isn't a good way, I continued the hunt and found another way.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945693/1276636) was helpful and I used the library posted there.

Follow these steps:

1. Import the library by adding this to your gradle file:

   ```
   compile 'org.solovyev.android.views:linear-layout-manager:0.5@aar'
   ```
2. set the `LayoutManager` like below:

   ```
   mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new org.solovyev.android.views.llm.LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));`
   ```
3. make sure that the view being inflated in the horizontal `RecyclerView` is `RelativeLayout` because other `LinearLayout` doesn't support this.
4. run your project and witness the magic!

Comment: I would like to ask, is this layout manager for the child or parent?

Comment: `mRecyclerView` is the nested `RecyclerView`.