# How to make recycler view start adding items from center?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

- I have a recyclerView with "Horziontal Linear Layout" as layout manager.
- Recycler View is in a frame layout, with layout_gravity = "center", and layout_width="wrap_content"
- I want recycler view start adding items from center.
- Here is what I want:

[image]

[image]

[image]

- And Here is what I am getting:

[image]

- You can see that in the last image items are added from left. I want it to add items from center as shown in the first three images .

Comment: Try to set center gravity to RecycleView.

Comment: Still unable to solve problem, any solutions please asap

Comment: Try and set recyclerviews width based on it's items. (n*itemWidth, n -> the number of items.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview

Problem solved, this was the solution.

Answer (score 12):

i had same issue and solved like this for my horizontal RecyclerView:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

**Here the main part is android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
and layout_width="wrap_content"**

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

[How do I make WRAP_CONTENT work on a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview)

This was the solution, I had to enforce the wrap_content for recycler view, So a custom Layout manager worked for me. Hope this will help others:)

Comment: The link is dead. Should learn how to use StackOverflow. Do not post links as they can go dead sometime in the future.