# RecyclerView wrap_content with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I've seen workarounds with `LinearLayoutManager`, but not with `GridLayoutManager`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you ellaborate? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @TheoK `RecyclerView` ignores the attribute `wrap_content` and assumes that it's height is 0. The issue is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview). There is a solution for `LinearLayoutManager` but not for `GridLayoutManager`.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using only one `RecyclerView` and using `getItemViewType(int position)` method in the adapter. Example [here](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html).

Answer (score 6):

According to the [announce](http://android-developers.blogspot.my/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) of a support library version 23.2.0 all default layout managers support auto-measurement now. So all WRAP_CONTENT and MATCH_PARENT should work correctly from this moment.

Don't forget to update version of a library in gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```