# Horizontal RecyclerView height wrap content not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-layoutparams

I have a custom horizontal RecyclerView which is inside a vertical listview. The problem is, I can't use wrap_content in recyclerView. Right now I am setting a height of 455dp. I tried a custom LinearLayoutManager too, it fixes the wrap_content problem but then, the recyclerView does not scroll horizontally.

Here is my custom RecyclerView :

```
public class FlingRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    int screenWidth;

    public FlingRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
    }

    public FlingRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
    }

    public FlingRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager();

//these four variables identify the views you see on screen.
        int lastVisibleView = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        int firstVisibleView = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        View firstView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstVisibleView);
        View lastView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastVisibleView);

//these variables get the distance you need to scroll in order to center your views.
//my views have variable sizes, so I need to calculate side margins separately.
//note the subtle difference in how right and left margins are calculated, as well as
//the resulting scroll distances.


        int leftMargin = (screenWidth - lastView.getWidth()) / 2;
        int rightMargin = (screenWidth - firstView.getWidth()) / 2 + firstView.getWidth();
        int leftEdge = lastView.getLeft();
        int rightEdge = firstView.getRight();
        int scrollDistanceLeft = leftEdge - leftMargin;
        int scrollDistanceRight = rightMargin - rightEdge;

//if(user swipes to the left)
        if (velocityX > 0) smoothScrollBy(scrollDistanceLeft, 0);
        else smoothScrollBy(-scrollDistanceRight, 0);

        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is my custom Layout Manager :

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                          int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
                width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
                }
            } else {
                height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
                }
            }
        }
        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                width = widthSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                height = heightSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the problem and how to fix that?

Comment: I went through a similar problem. The RecyclerView doesn't recalculate its size after other alements are drawn. But there may be an easy workaround. Let me see your layout file.

Comment: check [WRAP_CONTENT on RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35623177/2826147) answer.

Comment: Were you able to fix this with the new wrap_content specified in the answer? Asking since my recycler view isn't changing height dynamically... [Here's a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585286/horizontal-recyclerview-with-variable-item-heights-not-wrapping-properly) to my question related to the same

Comment: yes, I was able to fix this with wrap_content

Comment: @AmitTiwari how did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WRAP_CONTENT** in RecyclerView is now avaible with `Android Support Library 23.2.`  Update your library in gradle. You can find more detail [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)