# can i create a nestedScroll Layout like this?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

[image]

I think it can be achieved by `NestedScrollingChild` `NestedScrollingParent`.

But I can't really understand them.Who can help me out!

Product manager insists on the design.

The `ScrollView` contains a `LinearLayout` ,a "TabLayout" and a `ViewPager`.

The `ViewPager` contains 2 `fragment` contains `RecyclerView` or just only 2 `RecyclerView`.

When the `ScrollView` scroll to Bottom , the `RecyclerView` can scroll to Bottom.

When the `RecyclerView` scroll to Top , the `ScrollView` can scroll to Top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp" />
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"></TableLayout>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You can but its too hacky and not user friendly at all... i would recommend to redesign your app so you dont have to resort to this solution.

Comment: The product manager persist it!

Comment: Push back and say its silly and technically wrong and against standards....

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to achieve. If you just want to have ViewPager within ScrollView, just put your whole stuff into some layout (Linear, Relative, etc) and then wrap this layout with ScrollView. Maybe take a look into `overscrollMode` for RecyclerView to have both scrolls for Recycler and for ScrollView

Comment: The viewpager contains 2 recyclerview. I want that  them can scroll at some time.

Answer (score 6):

Just change your  **ScrollView** to **android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView**

Post your xml if that doesn't work

Comment: I put on my xml.There are 2 RecyclerView in ViewPager

Comment: what happens when you change ScrollView to android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

Comment: When i scroll one RecyclerVIew from bottom to top, I want the scrollView to scroll util recyclerview bottom align screen bottom.But the recyclerView scroll directly in a small space.I am going to sleep.Bye.

Answer (score 2):

ِYou can do that, but it's not good at all to use this type of layout

First you need add "wrap_content" abilty ViewPager and RecyclerView's

[ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content) and [RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview)

Now you can use scrollview easily, put all item in it

If you want some effect or something when user scrolling or some item get visible in scrolling you can get position of item then make listener on 
"OnScrollChangedListener" of scrollview