# Center Columns in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm trying to create a dynamic `RecyclerView` layout.  I am using a `GridLayoutManager` with three columns.

I need to wrap each grid item and center the columns (like attached).

I have tried a `StaggeredGridLayout`, I have tried a [WrapGridLayoutManager](https://gist.github.com/c0nnector/5f80e19d9ba6d562fbd5)  but neither of these worked.

Here is my `RecyclerView`:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/categories_grid"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and my `RecyclerView` item:

```
 <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/first_time_category_unselected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/black_colour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_status_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_follow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the decoration I'm using to implement grid spacing:

```
public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int halfSpace;

    public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
        this.halfSpace = space / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

        if (parent.getPaddingLeft() != halfSpace) {
            parent.setPadding(halfSpace, halfSpace, halfSpace, halfSpace);
            parent.setClipToPadding(false);
        }

        outRect.top = halfSpace;
        outRect.bottom = halfSpace;
        outRect.left = halfSpace;
        outRect.right = halfSpace;
    }
}
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: what I'm trying to achieve]

This is what I am getting:
[image]
If anyone can help on this I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: Looking to achieve a similar thing, did you ever manage to get this to work correctly?

Comment: also trying to do this. i used gridlayout manager and messed with the setSpanSize but then things got evenly spaced for just 2 columns . i wnated it tighter together like how you have it shown. so no one on the internet has been able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Staggered Grid Layout Manager`

as

```
  StagaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);
```

Here is [Link](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/) for reference

Comment: hi, as I mentioned in my op I have tried staggered grid layout but it didn't work, unless I can wrap the content width, it will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in recyclerView you could not arrange as you shown

```
<cuneyt.example.com.tagview.Tag.TagView
        android:id="@+id/tag_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

> Download repo from GIT https://github.com/Cutta/TagView

```
TagView tagGroup = (TagView)findviewById(R.id.tag_view);
//You can add one tag
tagGroup.addTag(Tag tag);
//You can add multiple tag via ArrayList
tagGroup.addTags(ArrayList tags);
//Via string array
 addTags(String[] tags);


//set click listener
  tagGroup.setOnTagClickListener(new OnTagClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTagClick(Tag tag, int position) {
        }
    });



//set delete listener
        tagGroup.setOnTagDeleteListener(new OnTagDeleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTagDeleted(final TagView view, final Tag tag, final int position) {
        }
    });
```

[How do I make WRAP_CONTENT work on a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview/29945693#29945693)

Comment: thank you but I need to use a recycler view and if I can wrap the content correctly I think the staggered layout will work