# Java reflection for mono android

Tags: java, c#, android, reflection, xamarin.android

I was facing [WRAP_CONTENT not work on a `RecyclerView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview) , so I googled it and found the workaround. When I tried to implement the workaround in c#, I was stuck at this line:

```
insetsDirtyField = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.class.getDeclaredField("mInsetsDirty");
```

Here I tried to port the original [java code](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/solovyev/android/views/llm/LinearLayoutManager.java),and ported code avilable in [gist](https://gist.github.com/jaganjan/3ee7059866cbaa5f155d)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I was stuck at this line:
>
> ```
> insetsDirtyField = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.class.getDeclaredField("mInsetsDirty");
> ```

The `.class` "keyword" in Java is equivalent to the `typeof()` keyword in C#, so this is (kinda/sorta) like:

```
var insetsDirtyField = typeof(RecyclerView.LayoutParams).GetDeclaredField("mInsetsDirty");
```

Except it isn't, because `typeof()` returns a `System.Type`, which doesn't know anything about `java.lang.Object` instances.

Instead, you should use [`Java.Lang.Class.FromType(Type)`](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Java.Lang.Class.FromType/p/System.Type/) to obtain a `Java.Lang.Class` instance, which will then allow you to use Java Reflection:

```
var klass = Java.Lang.Class.FromType (typeof (RecyclerView.LayoutParams));
var insetsDirtyField = klass.GetDeclaredField("mInsetsDirty");
```

Comment: clean explanation,its working updated gist,https://gist.github.com/jaganjan/3ee7059866cbaa5f155d

Comment: sorry for the late response ,im in india so only

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!