# Linear Layout not wrapping content

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:text="1."
    android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_edit_variety"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_grey600_48dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_edit_overflow"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_grey600_24dp" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch_edit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:buttonTint="@color/accent"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Stock"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_edit_variety_quantity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_edit_variety_quantity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Quantity" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_edit_variety_price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_edit_variety_price"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Price ($)" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have used wrap content, but the card view is still cutting my TextInputLayouts
How do I make them visible and wrap content the card view at the same time?
Thanks!

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview

Comment: it's not related to recycler view, if you copy this content and put it in a layout file, then the layout preview is not showing the content properly wrapped either...plz guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change layout_height of LinearLayout at:

```
.....
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_edit_overflow"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_grey600_24dp" />
......
```

to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Check once this code. Maybe it will helpful for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:text="1."
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_edit_variety"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/abcd"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_edit_overflow"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@drawable/abcd"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch_edit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:buttonTint="#1b4d2d"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Stock"
                android:textColor="#c11717" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_edit_variety_quantity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_edit_variety_quantity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Quantity" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_edit_variety_price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_edit_variety_price"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Price ($)" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```