# Shouldn't I be using a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement a schedule-like overview as List and as Grid View. Currently this works using a `RecyclerView` and swapping out the `LayoutManager` at Runtime. This works fine in general, but as soon as I tuned the grid cells to have a fixed height, I realised that the `RecyclerView` does not respect the `wrap_content` layout property and instead introduces whitespace between my grid items.

[image: Grid Layout]

I then stumbled over [more or less the same question for the linear LayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview) and the third-party provided specialisations of the LayoutManager. A quick searched revealed nothing similar for the `GridLayoutManager` and I am beginning to suspect I am going down the wrong road:

Apart from the easy switching between layouts, there seems to be no reason for me to work with a recycler view:

- I dont't require any special animation stuff.
- My adapter returns a fixed list without loading more items on demand.
- Actual recycling of items doesn't even take place.

So I am currently evaluating to simply switch to separate Fragments using an ordinary `ListView` and `GridView`. But this does feel a little like working against the intentions of Android ... After all, they introduced a single view that (in theory) should exactly do what I need.

Am I missing something obvious that could turn out to be painful when using those "legacy" `Views` to get the job done? Or are there maybe other, more specific Views that allow switching from linear to grid layouts apart from the `RecyclerView`?

If this should be of importance: I am using Xamarin.Android, not native Java. But I would be willing to port some code from Java to C#.

Comment: Can you show you code about onCreateViewHolder and the layout you use as item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this ticket:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772

It is not merged yet but soon should be merged and WRAP_CONTENT support should be available in the next version (`23.1.1+`) or the one after.