# Horizontal Recycler View with multiple item at once

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to show multiple itemview at once like this

[image]

I am using recycler view 23.2.1

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

My recycler view xml

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/gallary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
```

Corresponding Java code

```
 mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.gallary);
 mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

With this configuration I getting only one item at once. Like image below

[image]

It seems like wrap_content in recycler view is not working as the space between images are there. Is there anyway to remove the space between the items.

I found one bug related to wrap_contect in recycler view [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview) which is fixed. Not sure if this is causing the problem. Any help to fix this will be appreciated

My row view:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titletv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Testing"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp" />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/mainimgloading"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what does your row layout look like

Comment: i have updated the question with row view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parent LinearLayout for your row cannot be `match_parent` you must use `wrap_content` for your width or else you will get what you see there.

if you had a vertical recyclerview then you would be using `wrap_content` for your height and not your width

Comment: Interestingly I've changed my row width from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`, but it have not solved my problem.