# Why RecyclerView occupies entire layout space even though its layout_height attribute is set to wrap_content?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to add a `RecyclerView` such that when there is a child element it should be visible or else it shouldn't be visible. So I have set the `android:layout_height` attribute to `wrap_content` thinking that it does the above work.

But when I does that the content above `RecyclerView` in Android is visible and the rest of the layout space is occupying by the `RecyclerView`.

So now can we do anything to make `RecyclerView`s height to be dynamic?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="32dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="@string/feedback_header"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/feedback"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="start|top"
    android:hint="@string/feedback_description"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:minLines="5"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/darkGray"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/feedback_no_files"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/attach_file_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/feedback_disclosure"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/report"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkGray"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or xml file of the layouts?

Comment: Please provide he xml and the current output

Comment: I added them can u tell me why its happening

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make WRAP\_CONTENT work on a RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview)