# Adding fragments as a recycler view item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a NestedScrollView that contains a variety of layouts one of them being a recycler view. The hierarchy is something like shown below.

```
NestedScrollView
    ConstraintLayout
        TextView
        Many other layouts
        RecyclerView
```

From various articles I know this is a bad idea trying to have 2 scrolling views in the same direction and to solve it what I've come across is creating a layout out of all the other views, removing the ScrollView and then adding the layout as an item to the RecyclerView. However, other views have complicated logic. Would it be a terrible idea to convert the layout into a fragment and add that as an item to the RecyclerView? Is it a bad coding practice to follow this route?

The goal of this is to make sure the RecyclerView actually recycles its views.

Thanks

Comment: extends recylerview and expand it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview

Comment: this is different than my use case. I have two scrolls in the same direction and so setting height for recycler view as `wrap_content` creates all the items instead of creating only the visible ones

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom adapter where you set your layout individually:

```
class Adapter(var dataset: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf(), var context: Context?) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<BrowseAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

class ViewHolder(val layout: RelativeLayout) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(layout)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): ViewHolder {

    val cont = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.browse_item, parent, false) as RelativeLayout

    return ViewHolder(cont)
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataset.size
}


}
```

Comment: I understand using different layouts but the business logic for each of those layouts is too much to include in a single adapter. Which is why I'm asking about fragments.