# RecyclerView number of visible items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a horisontal RecyclerView in my app.
It has to show 2 images on the screen at a time (so width of each image has to be 50% of the screen).
For now it works fine but each item consums all width of the screen.

Here is my code

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_main_ads);
        LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mLinearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(tmp, R.layout.lv_main_screen);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is layout of an item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_main_ad"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/baner_gasoline"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I tried to use Layout_gravity="0.5",
But it doesn't help.

I tried to specify layout_width = ...dp but I can not get exactly half of the screen.

I am thinking of adding another ImageView into item layout, but in this case  I will have troubles with the adapter, because I want to implemnt circled (infinity) horizontal listview

here is my adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyHolder> {

    private List<Integer> mImages;
    private int itemLayout;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Integer>  imageResourceIds, int itemLayout) {
        this.mImages = imageResourceIds;
        this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
    }


    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
        return new MyHolder(v);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.adIv.setImageResource(mImages.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImages.size();
    }

    public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView adIv;

        private MyHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.adIv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_main_ad);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "each item consums all width of the screen". " Here is layout of an item" -> `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: Calculate the width of the screen & set the maximum number element that you want check ans

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira, i tried wrap_content, but it changes nothing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For You need to calculate the width of the screen and set the width dynamically below is the my code

Add below code in your `ViewHolder` initilisation

```
llImg = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.llImg);

            llImg.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (Utils.getScreenWidth(itemView.getContext()) / 2);
            llImg.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (Utils.getScreenWidth(itemView.getContext()) / 2);

            imgView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
```

The Layout file is here

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Make one Utils.java

```
public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {

        if (screenWidth == 0) {
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            screenWidth = size.x;
        }
        return screenWidth;
    }
```

Hope this will help you !

Comment: Check there is one method I added check now

Comment: I noticed an issue with this. It is that when I am scrolling images - I scroll them like one long image. So when I stop scrolling - it stops everywhere and partly 3 images can be shown. But when I stop scrolling should be shown only two, so  images must adjust to the edges (like it is hapeened with initial solution which I posted. When I stop this default one - always one image will be shown)

Comment: @Androider the divide count 2 or less/more depend on how many imageView do you want to show. For scroll problem check the LayoutManger

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade - in your logic, you have taken entire screen width, suppose the width of recycler view is not same with screen width, please tell me how to calculate the recycler view width ?

Comment: @Navas this link may be usefule for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517930/measure-recyclerview-before-it-appears

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade What I used to find the width of recylcler view is : created a RelativeLayout as a parent for Recycler view and get the width from parent 
`View view = relativeLayout.getWidth()` this code will return the width of parent of recylcer view in pixel. Basically recycler view width is same as that of parent width in my code. So this approach i used to to get the width..

Comment: @Navas your approach was good.if your parent layout has recyclerview

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade what is the value of screenWidth variable?