# set Recycler View Visible row count max 3 items even though it has more items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Stuck in this problem about `RecyclerView` Visible item count
Requirement :- 
`RecyclerView` has `3+` items but ,need to show 3 items (other items can be reached through scrolling)
`RecyclerView` has `<=3` items , need to show the full items

Recyclerview set adapter code

```
     cardoptionlist.clear();
    cardoptionlist.addAll(savedcards);
    cardoptionlist.add(new CardModel(true));

    if (cardOptionAdapter == null) {
        cardOptionAdapter = new CardOptionAdapter(getActivity(), cardoptionlist, this);
    }


    if (rcv_card_options.getLayoutManager() == null) {

        rcv_card_options.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    }

    rcv_card_options.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 0, false));
    rcv_card_options.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    rcv_card_options.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rcv_card_options.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    rcv_card_options.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    rcv_card_options.setAdapter(cardOptionAdapter);
```

Recyclerview Xml file

```
      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcv_card_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_app_color_border_8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"

        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"

        >
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: post some code!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @SanoopVasu. Please read first **[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: Put some code and efforts you have tried then tell us what problem are you facing

Comment: code added please check

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61676276/803682

Answer (score -1):

this can be help to you

```
 public void setHeight(final View convertView) {
    final int height = mRecyclerView.getMeasuredHeight() / 3;
    convertView.setLayoutParams(newAbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height));
}
```

Comment: i think the code is to set the recyclerview 1/3 height. but i need the  height of recycleview as sum of first 3 items .

Comment: did you try put code on adapter

bcs this is work for me.

Comment: hi when i need to call this function setHeight()

Comment: @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder, int position) {
        setHeight(imageViewHolder.mainParantView);
    }